# SQLITE results inconsistency

Tags: sqlite

I am summarising the outputs of a survey, stored in a sqlite database file, and have a view defined as follows - this is meant to show entries in the `valid response` view where the respondent has indicated that EITHER:

(a) they are meeting the requirements already; OR,

(b) they aren't meeting all requirements, but the associated actions in place will be complete by the end of the year (31/12/2020):

```
CREATE VIEW complete_dec20 AS
SELECT *
FROM valid_response
WHERE 
(impact_answer NOT IN ("Fully","Yes","N/A") AND
td__update_leg_doc <= "2020-12-31" AND
td__update_proc <= "2020-12-31" AND
td__update_op_proc <= "2020-12-31" AND
td__update_tech <= "2020-12-31" AND
td__training <= "2020-12-31") OR
impact_answer IN ("Fully","Yes","N/A")
```

The records included in the view are correct, however, when I query the results from the `valid_response` view that are not included in the view, there are some strange results:

```
SELECT *
FROM valid_response
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM complete_dec20);
```

e.g.

```
id,impact_answer,td__update_leg_doc,td__update_proc,td__update_op_proc,td__update_tech,td__training
7,Partially,2020-12-31,,,,
```

Based on the date of `2020-12-31` and answer of `'Partially'`, this should be in the `complete_dec20` view.

Can you explain why it isn't / what I'm missing?

Comment: I can suggest that maybe the current logic in the view is not correct.  The query you are using to find non matches looks fine to me though.

Comment: you could test your logic by hardcoding some values to null. I believe that null handling might not be working as you would expect.

Comment: I assume that a column like `id` can't be `null`, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Based on the date of 2020-12-31 and answer of 'Partially', this should
> be in the complete_dec20 view

This should be in the `complete_dec20` view only if **all** of these conditions are `true`:

```
td__update_leg_doc <= '2020-12-31' AND
td__update_proc <= '2020-12-31' AND
td__update_op_proc <= '2020-12-31' AND
td__update_tech <= '2020-12-31' AND
td__training <= '2020-12-31'
```

Are they?
I don't think so.
If they were `true` then the id would be returned by `complete_dec20`.

Also, the `WHERE` clause of `complete_dec20` can be a bit simpler because there is no need to check `impact_answer NOT IN ('Fully','Yes','N/A')`:

```
CREATE VIEW complete_dec20 AS
SELECT *
FROM valid_response
WHERE impact_answer IN ('Fully','Yes','N/A')
      OR
      (
        td__update_leg_doc <= '2020-12-31' AND
        td__update_proc <= '2020-12-31' AND
        td__update_op_proc <= '2020-12-31' AND
        td__update_tech <= '2020-12-31' AND
        td__training <= '2020-12-31'
      )
```

Or even simpler with the function `MAX()`:

```
CREATE VIEW complete_dec20 AS
SELECT *
FROM valid_response
WHERE impact_answer IN ('Fully','Yes','N/A')
      OR
      MAX(
        td__update_leg_doc,
        td__update_proc,
        td__update_op_proc,
        td__update_tech,
        td__training 
      ) <= '2020-12-31'
```